# Disable autocomplete for certain classes, Visual Studio Code, Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm not entirely sure this is an autocomplete issue, but I think it is. When I am editing a script in Visual Studio Code, without fail, every single time I try to call a method from an object and type a period, it shows me these completely irrelevant options. So, I don't want to disable autocomplete altogether, because occasionally, it does show me function names from modules when I type a period, but this other case happens so often it's really annoying. Not to mention, when I press the spacebar to try to get it to go away, it doesn't (like if I want to press enter to go to the next line). Instead, it will place the first selection in the autocomplete menu, which is never want I want. So I have to use my mouse and advance to the other line. Cumbersome and unnecessary.

So maybe I need to know, how to remove these certain classes from autocomplete? Or if someone knows how to get what I need in other ways, that would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to selectively turn off auto-complete like you're asking for. You can install [IntelliCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode) which will use machine learning to suggest completions that should help make them more relevant, or you can turn off the automatic display of completions and require that you hit e.g. Ctrl+space to make the options appear.

You can also try using Jedi or the Microsoft Python Language Server to change the IntelliSense provider (depending on what your current `"python.jediEnabled"` setting is set to).

Comment: Thanks Brett, I will try some of these. If I can get any of them to work, I'll come back and mark this as the answer.